# PHP->MySQL Form - Validation

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've got a dilema, I've got my database created, my input form works, however I'm looking to add validation to the POST so that certain things cant be entered, I can release snippets of code if needed however I can't find what I'm looking for.

My form basically

```
<input type="text" name="id1" placeholder="Pick a number">
<input type="text" name="id2" placeholder="Pick another number">
```

However, I would like to display an error if they pick the same number

> EG: IF ID1 == ID2 then ECHO error.

However I'm unsure of the code, I have a simple PHP Mysql form.

Comment: you should also validate they're numbers. Try googling, there's about a billion and one pages which will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
 if($_POST['id1'] == $_POST['id2']) {
        echo 'error';
    }
```

Comment: Taa, this was exactly what I was looking for, merged this with the success and fail of @guest420420 to work out what needed to go where, but this was what I wanted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

on the action of your form i.e you define in your action attribute of form `action='somepage.php` write below code.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id1']) && isset($_REQUEST['id2'])){
    if($_REQUEST['id1'] >= $_REQUEST['id2']){
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like A long winded way of doing it?.. Thanks though if Madhan's doesnt work, I'll give it a shot. :)

Comment: I say a bit more secure way to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, use typecasting plus check if posts are set.. e.g.

```
<?php 

$id1 = isset($_POST['id1']) ? (int) $_POST['id1'] : 0;
$id2 = isset($_POST['id2']) ? (int) $_POST['id2'] : 0;

if(!empty($id1) && !empty($id2) && $id1 !== $id){
// success
} else {
// fail
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the success & fail to work out what needed to go where, but again it was an unnecessary complication haha!  +1

Comment: Not unnecessary ;) They are needed if you want complete security.